# Convolution of DQ-Modules

Tags: sheaf-theory, d-modules, sheaf-cohomology, coherent-sheaves

On page 92 of [Deformation Quantization Modules](http://arxiv.org/abs/1003.3304) Kashiwara and Schapira define two different convolution products for DQ-modules that differ by whether one uses  $Rp_{13*}$ or $Rp_{13!}$ to push forward. Unfortunately, I cannot find where these operations are defined in the paper.

I was convinced that they were just the ordinary push forward and push forward with proper supports for $\underline{\mathbb{Z}[h]}_{X_1 \times X_2 \times X_3}$ modules but the first appearance of the shriek push forward on page 53 says it is some natural operation for modules over algebroids (unfortunately there is still no definition).

What are $Rp_{13*}$ and $Rp_{13!}$?